# Error en clausula where al tratar de obtener porcentaje en sentencia sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente sentencia en la cual , haciendo uso de tablas temporales trato de realizar un where que en base al total de días me permita filtrar solo el 60% de días que laboro.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TEMPTABLA') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLA;END 
            CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLA(COD INT,CEDULA VARCHAR(13) ,EMPLEADO VARCHAR(250),SECCION VARCHAR(100),FECING date,
            FECNAC DATE,EDAD INT, FECAFI INT, DIAS DATE,FECULTAF INT,
            ESTADO VARCHAR(2),PAGO VARCHAR(10));
            
            INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLA(COD,CEDULA,EMPLEADO,SECCION,FECING,FECNAC,EDAD,FECAFI,DIAS,FECULTAF,ESTADO,PAGO) 
            SELECT E.EMPL_COD AS COD,
            E.EMPL_CEDU AS CEDULA,
            MAX(ISNULL(E.EMPL_APELL,'')) + SPACE(1) + MAX(ISNULL(E.EMPL_NOMB,'')) AS OBRERO,
            S.SECCION AS SECCION,
            (SELECT DISTINCT E.EMPL_FECH AS FECHING),
            E.EMPL_FEC_NAC AS FECNAC,
            (cast(datediff(dd,E.EMPL_FEC_NAC,GETDATE()) / 365.25 as int)) AS EDAD,
            E.EMPL_FECH_AF AS AFI,
             HM.MOV_FECHA AS TOTDIAS,
              E.EMPL_FECH_UAF AS FECAFI,
            E.EMPL_STATUS AS ESTADO,
             E.EMPL_NOTA AS PAGO
            FROM HIS_MOV_HORA AS HM 
            INNER JOIN TBL_EMPLEADO AS E ON E.EMPL_COD =  HM.MOV_CODEMPLEADO 
            INNER JOIN TBL_SECCION S ON  e.EMPL_AREA = S.ID_CODIGO AND(HM.MOV_FECHA>='01/09/2021' AND HM.MOV_FECHA<='30/09/2021') 
            GROUP BY 
            E.EMPL_COD,S.SECCION,E.EMPL_CEDU,E.EMPL_FECH, E.EMPL_NOTA,HM.Mov_Fecha,E.EMPL_FECH_AF
            ,E.EMPL_FEC_NAC,E.EMPL_NOTA,E.EMPL_FECH_UAF,e.EMPL_STATUS ORDER BY TOTDIAS 
            
            INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLA(COD,CEDULA,EMPLEADO,SECCION,FECING,FECNAC,EDAD,FECAFI,DIAS,FECULTAF,ESTADO,PAGO) 
            SELECT E.EMPL_COD AS COD,
            E.EMPL_CEDU AS CEDULA,
            MAX(ISNULL(E.EMPL_APELL,'')) + SPACE(1) + MAX(ISNULL(E.EMPL_NOMB,'')) AS OBRERO,                
            S.SECCION AS SECCION,
            (SELECT DISTINCT E.EMPL_FECH AS FECHING),
            E.EMPL_FEC_NAC AS FECNAC,
            (cast(datediff(dd,E.EMPL_FEC_NAC,GETDATE()) / 365.25 as int)) AS EDAD,
            E.EMPL_FECH_AF AS AFI,
            (HM.MOV_FECHA) AS TOTDIAS,
             E.EMPL_FECH_UAF AS FECAFI,
            E.EMPL_STATUS AS ESTADO,
            E.EMPL_NOTA AS PAGO
            FROM HIS_MOV_PROD AS HM 
            INNER JOIN TBL_EMPLEADO AS E ON E.EMPL_COD =  HM.MOV_CODEMPLEADO INNER JOIN TBL_SECCION S ON 
            E.EMPL_AREA = S.ID_CODIGO AND(HM.MOV_FECHA>='01/09/2021' AND HM.MOV_FECHA<='30/09/2021') 
            GROUP BY E.EMPL_COD,S.SECCION,E.EMPL_CEDU, HM.Mov_Fecha,E.EMPL_FECH,E.EMPL_NOTA,
            E.EMPL_FECH_AF,E.EMPL_FEC_NAC,E.EMPL_NOTA,E.EMPL_FECH_UAF,e.EMPL_STATUS
            ORDER BY TOTDIAS 
            
            ;WITH VISTA AS(SELECT COD,CEDULA,EMPLEADO,SECCION, FECING,FECNAC,EDAD ,FECAFI,COUNT(DISTINCT(DIAS)) AS DIAS,PAGO 
            ,FECULTAF,ESTADO
            FROM #TEMPTABLA 
             WHERE ((ESTADO !='P' AND ESTADO != 'NA' )AND (PAGO !='T'AND PAGO !='I'))
             GROUP BY COD,CEDULA,EMPLEADO,SECCION,FECING,FECNAC,EDAD ,FECAFI,FECULTAF,ESTADO,PAGO),
            
            VISTAFINAL AS(SELECT COD,CEDULA,EMPLEADO,SECCION, FECING,FECNAC,EDAD ,FECAFI,DIAS,PAGO 
            ,FECULTAF,ESTADO
            FROM VISTA
             WHERE DIAS> (DIAS*(60/100))-- AQUI DEBERIA SALIR 18, PERO NO SE CALCULA CORRECTAMENTE)
            
            SELECT COD,CEDULA,EMPLEADO,SECCION, FECING,FECNAC,EDAD ,FECAFI,DIAS,PAGO 
            ,FECULTAF,ESTADO
            FROM VISTAFINAL
            ORDER BY DIAS DESC
```

Actualmente al ejecutar este query me arroja el siguiente resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y debería arrojar el resultado de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que estaría realizando de manera errónea?, de antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Podrias aclarar cual es la diferencia entre los resultados mostrados?

Comment: El primer resultado es usando el `where DIAS> (DIAS*(60/100))` y el segundo resultado es usando el `where DIAS> 18`, el 18 debería salir automáticamente en el primer where en base a la condición tomando el numero mas alto del resultado de la variable días

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a la ayuda de colaboradores en otros foros solo tenia que hacer uso de la función `DATEDIFF`, que me hacia la resta entre la fecha de inicio y fecha fin con lo cual procedo a calcular el 50 o 60% dependiendo lo que pida el cliente.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DiasLaboradosEmpleadoFP]
@FECHAI DATETIME,
@FECHAF DATETIME
AS
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TEMPTABLA') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLA;END 
                CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLA(COD INT,CEDULA VARCHAR(13) ,EMPLEADO VARCHAR(250),SECCION VARCHAR(100),FECING date,
                FECNAC DATE,EDAD INT, FECAFI INT, DIAS DATE,FECULTAF INT,
                ESTADO VARCHAR(2),PAGO VARCHAR(10));
                
                INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLA(COD,CEDULA,EMPLEADO,SECCION,FECING,FECNAC,EDAD,FECAFI,DIAS,FECULTAF,ESTADO,PAGO) 
                SELECT E.EMPL_COD AS COD,
                E.EMPL_CEDU AS CEDULA,
                MAX(ISNULL(E.EMPL_APELL,'')) + SPACE(1) + MAX(ISNULL(E.EMPL_NOMB,'')) AS OBRERO,
                S.SECCION AS SECCION,
                (SELECT DISTINCT E.EMPL_FECH AS FECHING),
                E.EMPL_FEC_NAC AS FECNAC,
                (cast(datediff(dd,E.EMPL_FEC_NAC,GETDATE()) / 365.25 as int)) AS EDAD,
                E.EMPL_FECH_AF AS AFI,
                 HM.MOV_FECHA AS TOTDIAS,
                  E.EMPL_FECH_UAF AS FECAFI,
                E.EMPL_STATUS AS ESTADO,
                 E.EMPL_NOTA AS PAGO
                FROM HIS_MOV_HORA AS HM 
                INNER JOIN TBL_EMPLEADO AS E ON E.EMPL_COD =  HM.MOV_CODEMPLEADO 
                INNER JOIN TBL_SECCION S ON  e.EMPL_AREA = S.ID_CODIGO AND(HM.MOV_FECHA>=@FECHAI AND HM.MOV_FECHA<=@FECHAF) 
                GROUP BY 
                E.EMPL_COD,S.SECCION,E.EMPL_CEDU,E.EMPL_FECH, E.EMPL_NOTA,HM.Mov_Fecha,E.EMPL_FECH_AF
                ,E.EMPL_FEC_NAC,E.EMPL_NOTA,E.EMPL_FECH_UAF,e.EMPL_STATUS ORDER BY TOTDIAS 
                
                INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLA(COD,CEDULA,EMPLEADO,SECCION,FECING,FECNAC,EDAD,FECAFI,DIAS,FECULTAF,ESTADO,PAGO) 
                SELECT E.EMPL_COD AS COD,
                E.EMPL_CEDU AS CEDULA,
                MAX(ISNULL(E.EMPL_APELL,'')) + SPACE(1) + MAX(ISNULL(E.EMPL_NOMB,'')) AS OBRERO,                
                S.SECCION AS SECCION,
                (SELECT DISTINCT E.EMPL_FECH AS FECHING),
                E.EMPL_FEC_NAC AS FECNAC,
                (cast(datediff(dd,E.EMPL_FEC_NAC,GETDATE()) / 365.25 as int)) AS EDAD,
                E.EMPL_FECH_AF AS AFI,
                (HM.MOV_FECHA) AS TOTDIAS,
                 E.EMPL_FECH_UAF AS FECAFI,
                E.EMPL_STATUS AS ESTADO,
                E.EMPL_NOTA AS PAGO
                FROM HIS_MOV_PROD AS HM 
                INNER JOIN TBL_EMPLEADO AS E ON E.EMPL_COD =  HM.MOV_CODEMPLEADO INNER JOIN TBL_SECCION S ON 
                E.EMPL_AREA = S.ID_CODIGO AND(HM.MOV_FECHA>=@FECHAI AND HM.MOV_FECHA<=@FECHAF) 
                GROUP BY E.EMPL_COD,S.SECCION,E.EMPL_CEDU, HM.Mov_Fecha,E.EMPL_FECH,E.EMPL_NOTA,
                E.EMPL_FECH_AF,E.EMPL_FEC_NAC,E.EMPL_NOTA,E.EMPL_FECH_UAF,e.EMPL_STATUS
                ORDER BY TOTDIAS 
                
               ;WITH VISTA AS(SELECT COD,CEDULA,EMPLEADO,SECCION, FECING,FECNAC,EDAD ,FECAFI,COUNT(DISTINCT(DIAS)) AS DIAS,PAGO 
                ,FECULTAF,ESTADO
                FROM #TEMPTABLA 
                 WHERE (ESTADO !='P' AND ESTADO != 'NA' )AND (PAGO !='T'AND PAGO !='I')
                 GROUP BY COD,CEDULA,EMPLEADO,SECCION, FECING,FECNAC,EDAD ,FECAFI,PAGO,FECULTAF,ESTADO),
                
                VISTAFINAL AS(SELECT COD,CEDULA,EMPLEADO,SECCION, FECING,FECNAC,EDAD ,FECAFI,DIAS AS DIAS,PAGO 
                ,FECULTAF,ESTADO
                FROM VISTA
                 WHERE DIAS * 1.0> (DATEDIFF(DAY, @FECHAI, @FECHAF)*1.0*(60*1.0/100)))
                
                SELECT COD,CEDULA,EMPLEADO,SECCION, FECING,FECNAC,EDAD ,FECAFI,DIAS AS DIAS,PAGO 
                ,FECULTAF,ESTADO
                FROM VISTAFINAL
                GROUP BY COD,CEDULA,EMPLEADO,SECCION, FECING,FECNAC,EDAD ,FECAFI,PAGO,DIAS,FECULTAF,ESTADO
                ORDER BY DIAS DESC
```